# IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process

Tags: asp.net, freetextbox

I have this code in my asp.net project:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Server.MapPath(@"~/AboutUs.txt")))
            {
                sw.Write(FreeTextBox1.Text);
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
                lblError.Text = "تغییرات با موفقیت ذخیره شد.";
                lblError.CssClass = "success";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "خطایی روی داده است!" + "\n" + ex.ToString();
            lblError.CssClass = "error";

        }
        finally
        {
            lblError.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

Sometimes (not always) when I hit `btnSave` following error is occurred:

> IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process

Why?

Comment: When two people hit the button at the same time, that the first one is still writing to the file when the second enters it? Besides that, i'm not sure what happens when dispose the streamwriter IN the using statement; the using statement already calls the dispose method. In the docs I also didn't find the need to call the close method. I would also move the lblError.xxxx code outside the using statement. And to complete: you can also use the `File.WriteAllText()` method.

Comment: Try @Michel 's suggestions first, I also think the most likely cause for the problem is multiple button clicks (implement some kind of locking mechanism to prevent it). Also, you don't want to display a full stacktrace as error message and "\n" wo'nt work as newline character on a web page, use "<br/>" instead. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You just Run your application after see windows task manager-->Processes, any notepad.exe running you just right click then click end process . .